# status for latest entry in sql

Tags: sql, subquery

i'm new to sql and i was wondering if i could get some help

i have a table where different entities return a pass/fail and a timestamp

i'd like to output the entities that have returned a PASS on their latest run-through

so far I have

```
SELECT ENTITY
FROM TABLE T
WHERE STATUS IN (
        SELECT MAX(T2.DATE) FROM TABLE T2)
AND STATUS='PASS'
```

which isn't right, but i don't know enough to fix it

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dngAS.png)

```
  entity    status  date
    A   PASS    20180703
    A   FAIL    20180703
    A   PASS    20180704
    B   PASS    20180304
    B   FAIL    20180327
    B   FAIL    20180513
    B   PASS    20180703
    C   PASS    20180211
    C   FAIL    20180304
    D   FAIL    20180622
    D   PASS    20180703
    D   PASS    20180716
    D   PASS    20180725
    D   FAIL    20180816
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using aggregation for this.  Here is one method:

```
select entity
from t
group by entity
having max(date) = max(case when status = 'PASS' then date end);
```

This compares the maximum date for the entity with the maximum date of a `'PASS'`.  When these are equal, then the last status is `'PASS"`.